# Why does oracle connection opens so slow on mac os sierra?

Tags: oracle, macos, docker, database-connection

I work on Docker with an oracle-xe-11g image. When I connect via ssh to Docker container, the connection is established immediately. But when I want to connect to oracle database using localhost:49162 ( port is forwarded to container's 1521 ) it will take about 15 - 25 seconds to open each connection.

It doesn't matter if I use JDBC connection or SQLDeveloper.
I have read that problem could be connected with DNS resolution, but I wasn't able to find any sufficient solution.

[Slow DNS lookups](http://gotofritz.net/blog/geekery/os-x-dns-lookups-too-slow-for-local-hosts/)

#### My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

#### My resolv.conf:

```
search home
nameserver 62.179.1.60
nameserver 62.179.1.61
```

System version:
macOS Sierra 10.12.3.

Has someone faced similar issues?

Comment: What happens if you `telnet localhost 49162` instead? Only immediate thought is the listener on the Docker is trying to do a reverse DNS lookup from your incoming connection and that is slow/timing out, perhaps. Is there anything relevant in the listener log? Can you see what source IP is reported in v$session (maybe localhost but the tunnelling might be comfusing it) and try to look that up from the Docker command line?

Comment: telnet localhost 49162
        Trying ::1...
        Connected to localhost.
        Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: Yes, but... is that quick, or also slow?

Comment: It was quick, instant.

Comment: Then its's something the Docker or listener is doing, not anything to do with macOS. I'd look into the reverse lookup angle from the Docker. Maybe add the ssh setup info to the question too, and what the connection looks like from the far end.

Comment: In v$session I couldn't find any IP address, only MACHINE column which is set to my local hostname. Moreover, I have added that hostname to DNS Search Domains and this completely resolve my issue !

Comment: @DamianPotyralski Could you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, When I followed the [link](http://gotofritz.net/blog/geekery/os-x-dns-lookups-too-slow-for-local-hosts/) you mentioned in the question, and in particular when I changed the first line of my `/etc/hosts` of my mac from:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

to:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost Muhammads-MacBook-Pro.local
```

Where **Muhammads-MacBook-Pro.local** is the output of the command `hostname`

Then it worked fine.